# Excel messes with my formula when copied, how can I stop I stop it changing one part but not the other?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I'm working with an old database system that is being updated, previously it ran across many different files, one with emails, one with numbers, you get the idea.

Anyway, in trying to compile in to one file, I've hit a snag, some people don't have a number or an email etc, this means I can't just copy the old data over (PersonID 5's phone would be in PersonID 4's space)

So what I did was use a Vlookup Formula, had some troubles with it and this morning I realised what the problem was.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'PhoneType - Email'!B1:V29190,3,FALSE)
```

I'll break this up quick, A is the column with the PersonID in, email is the worksheet the emails are in, B1:V29190 should be selecting the whole table and 3 is the column that PersonID is in in that worksheet.

Basically, I need A to change (A2, A3, A4) in line with the row it's in BUT I need B1:V29190 to stay constant as currently Excel tries to be clever and progresses it with each copy paste.

How can I do this?

Many thanks,

icey

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2,'PhoneType - Email'!B$1:V$29190,3,FALSE)`

Comment: @Jeeped Perfect! So a Dollar sign makes a them a constant? 

Thanks for the help, you want to throw this down as an answer I'll accept it and we can all go home :P

Comment: Actually, the names are **Absolute** and **Relative**. The **$** turns either a row or column *absolute* so they do not change when filled or copied to a new location. You were filling down rows so you only needed to 'lock' the row numbers as absolute. If you put the cursor into the cell address and hit [F4], you will see all of hte combinations.

Comment: @Jeeped ok, thanks very much for the information and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are **Absolute** and **Relative** cell references. The **$** turns either a row or column *absolute* so they do not change when filled or copied to a new location. You were filling down rows so you only needed to 'lock' the row numbers as absolute. If you put the cursor into the cell address and hit <kbd>F4</kbd>, you will see the first of the combinations. Keep tapping <kbd>F4</kbd> to see other combinations.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'PhoneType - Email'!B$1:V$29190,3,FALSE)
```