# How to find the maximum value from a column using another column as criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drag

I have a dataset with person and values. I need to find the maximum value for each person. I wrote a function to find the maximum value for each person and gave 'ctrl+shift+Enter'.

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A34=A2,B2:B34))
```

When I drag this formula for all the person, the last few values for each person are not getting formulated correctly. Attached screenshot for reference. What is wrong that I am doing here? [image: Screenshot of dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=MAX(IF(A$2:A$34=A2, B$2:B$34))
```

... with CSE then drag down.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145273/excel-messes-with-my-formula-when-copied-how-can-i-stop-i-stop-it-changing-one/33145470#33145470) for more information.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. It would be helpful to have an explanation for adding $ in the column values :)